# Check SecurityStamp every request using Access Token asp.net identiy

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-identity

I'm using asp.net identiy to protect my api, 
I use the following function to create Access Tokenfor users when they log in

```
private string GenerateAccessToken(string userName, string role)
        {
            ClaimsIdentity oAuthIdentity = new ClaimsIdentity(Startup.OAuthOptions.AuthenticationType);

            oAuthIdentity.AddClaim(new Claim(ClaimTypes.Name, userName));
            oAuthIdentity.AddClaim(new Claim(ClaimTypes.Role, role));

            AuthenticationTicket ticket = new AuthenticationTicket(oAuthIdentity, new AuthenticationProperties());

            DateTime currentUtc = DateTime.UtcNow;
            ticket.Properties.IssuedUtc = currentUtc;
            ticket.Properties.ExpiresUtc = currentUtc.Add(TimeSpan.FromDays(365));

            string accessToken = Startup.OAuthOptions.AccessTokenFormat.Protect(ticket);

            Request.Headers.Authorization = new System.Net.Http.Headers.AuthenticationHeaderValue("Bearer", accessToken);

            return accessToken;
        }
```

Everything is fine until I perform an account password update, after that I update SecurityStamp

```
UserManager.UpdateSecurityStampAsync(loggedinUser.Id);
```

but the problem is that the token can still be used to call my api without any problem. So how do I check SecurityStamp with each request?

Answer (score 0):

You can check `SecurityStamp` using the `JwtBearerEvents` configured in `startup.cs` or `program.cs` depending of your .Net version.

This is a very simple version of `SecurityStamp` validation (.Net 6):

```
builder.Services
    .AddAuthentication(JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme)
    .AddJwtBearer(cfg =>
    {
        cfg.Events = new JwtBearerEvents
        {
            OnTokenValidated = async (ctx) =>
            {
                var signInManager = ctx.HttpContext.RequestServices
                    .GetRequiredService<SignInManager<ApplicationUser>>();

                var user = await signInManager.ValidateSecurityStampAsync(ctx.Principal);

                if (user == null)
                {
                    ctx.Fail("Invalid Security Stamp");
                }
            }
        };
        // more code...
    });
```

Note:
For this example to work correctly, you need to ensure that you are packaging the `SecurityStamp` along with the user's claims during token creation, as in the example below.

```
var identityOptions = _config.Get<ClaimsIdentityOptions>();

claims.Add(new Claim(identityOptions.SecurityStampClaimType, user.SecurityStamp));
```

Comment: Also, you can use a constant `"AspNet.Identity.SecurityStamp"` claim type instead of retrieving from configuration and hope no one changes it. Check [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.identity.claimsidentityoptions.securitystampclaimtype) page.